# Ice material for web 3d

Tags: materials, webgl

Hey there we’re doing a web VR lab project and the programmer is using “a-frame”, so that means using a limited PBR process.

So any ideas on how I could make a realistic looking ice material, at the moment mine looks like a 90’s game.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the ICE shader (procedural) from here:

https://gumroad.com/trapanidigitaldesign

Bake textures to use them as PBR. 
Done.